# Image keyboard support in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, android-softkeyboard, android-7.1-nougat, android-textinputedittext

[Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/image-keyboard) states that:

> With Android 7.1 (API level 25), the Android SDK includes the Commit Content API, which provides a universal way for IMEs to send images and other rich content directly to a text editor in an app.

However, when I use the React Native's [TextInput](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.56/textinput#content) component and select a GIF from Android's keyboard, I receive the following message (see screenshot):

> This text field does not support GIF insertion from the keyboard.

[image: This text field does not support GIF insertion from the keyboard.]

How can I add support for this functionality to a React Native app? Ideally I'd like a component that provides a callback to handle the URI received by `commitContent()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a pull request that adds support from 3 months ago.  I'm not clear why it isn't merged at this point...
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/26088